# Plugin for webcam integration in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am working in a project where I should integrate webcam to my web application and record the video and save it in local file system.Can any1 tell me which free api or plugin or gem I can  use for this?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

This might be late for the party, but I created a gem that will allow you to capture photos easily:

Headshot - Easy web cam integration for Ruby on Rails.

http://headshot.hypermediasoft.com/

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for you

http://lassebunk.dk/2011/02/19/paperclip-jpegcam-webcam-rails3/